# Jest mocking package methods

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a method named 'download' from the package named 'download-git-repo'.

```
const download = require('download-git-repo')
```

And in the __ mocks __ folder, I have added a JavaScript file named download-git-repo.js and in that file I have added the following

```
const download = jest.createMockFromModule('download-git-repo');
module.exports = download
```

I'm calling this download method within another method which is under test.But my test is failing am i missing out something ???

Comment: `mocks` folder should be called `__mocks__`

Comment: ya, I have the same

Comment: The mock file is inside `download-git-repo` folder?
Try to export simple object and check in the tests that you get it.

Comment: Yes,  its the package that has to be mocked

Comment: You should have something like, `__mocks__/download-git-repo/index.js`